# Java Programming - Calculating %

Tags: java

What is 3 % 5?

Plus how do you figure this out?

I really have no idea how to calculate this.  I have done some research but everything is blocked.

Comment: It's 3. 3 isn't dividable by 5, so the remainder is 3, which is what the modulo operator gives you.

Comment: % is the modulus operator in Java and many other languages.  So it checks what the remainder is after you perform the division, in this case, what is the remainder of 3/5, which is 3.

Comment: Exactly how much research have you carried out?

Comment: @kolossus in all fairness, you can't use puntuation signs or things like `%` on Google.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that references regarding the module operator are "blocked".

Comment: Next time try searching like http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+what+is+%22%25%22+operator

Comment: That's it: stackoverflow is the search site using special charaters :)

Comment: @AntonH in all fairness, if you just write 3%5 in the google search bar, =3 pops up as an suggestion and if you click search the first result is a calculator showing 3 as an result. [link](https://www.google.de/search?q=3%255&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=a2zaU7H3B6yH8Qe22IGoBg#channel=sb&q=3%255&rls=org.mozilla:de:official)

Comment: @Gumbo I knew Google worked as a calculator, but I didn't know this. It even gives the name 'modulo'. You learn every day.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You can know a lot about math, and still not have learned that the `%` infix operator is bound to the modulo operation in Java.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [Modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): which gives the remainder during a division.
example

```
46%9=1  as 46-(5*9)=1
38%6=2  as 38-(6*6)=2
3%5= 3.   As 3-(5*0)=3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Modulo operator, it essentially calculates the remainder.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator is the remainder operation.

To test you could try:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println(3%5);
    }    
}
```

Comment: OP end up with result and don't know, how the result came :P

Comment: We assume he came up with this result... Surely being able to test and substitute values would allow him to see the behaviour!